# Jerk detection in accelerometer data

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, scipy, peak-detection

I want to detect jerk from accelerator data i.e. values beyond 1.57 m/s^2, but due to the high frequency nature of the sensor (400 values per second), it gives multiple jerks instead of one.
How can I solve this?

***Result coming now***
[image]

***Desired result***
[image]

1. I do not need more jerk updates as it gives many false positives. If accelerometer value breaches 1.57m/s^2 and comes back below it I consider that a jerk.
2. Problem that I want to solve is build a android app that uses accelerometer data to detect faults on railway tracks.
3. I am resorting to someone's advise and doing bandpass filtering and then Hilbert transform on the data then use find peaks function , is this correct approach if so how to proceed further ; if not do suggest one.
4. Multiple peaks is what i mean i.e. multiple local maximas instead of one.

**EDIT Updates**

I am building a mobile based real time accelerometer Oscillation Monitoring System.

The csv of all data contains x,y,z accelerometer value,jerk time in UTC,latitude , longitude of real time train journey: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k47ScyTRr7tr9ZCbSPfHdYApCy53s0E7/view?usp=sharing

The plots are in form of html which are exported from plotly kindly download them and them open on remote machine.

***Plot of raw accelerometer data*** :https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cuJhjrpvvvN1BIDIxn_tBeo2Yyn4Blab/view?usp=sharing

***The first step,is a bandpass filter between 0.3 to 12 Hz (Plot):***

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_3ZjAHwFcCrV3nBGvRXxY9eWh2QwpWIS/view?usp=sharing

***Code:***

```py
def bandpass(signal):
    fs = 380
    lowcut = 0.3
    highercut = 12.0
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut/nyq
    high = highercut/nyq
    order = 2
    b , a  = scipy.signal.butter(order,[low,high],'bandpass',analog=False)
    y = scipy.signal.filtfilt(b,a,signal,axis=0)
    return(y)
```

***Followed by an envelope detector,of which I have compared RMS and Hilbert(Plot):***
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19cL8kZuh5hvB0AW5zKAKZy0uTBlaMVJS/view?usp=sharing

***Code:***

Hilbert

```py
def hilbert_transform(x, N=None, axis=-1):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    if np.iscomplexobj(x):
        raise ValueError("x must be real.")
    if N is None:
        N = x.shape[axis]
    if N <= 0:
        raise ValueError("N must be positive.")

    Xf = fft(x, N, axis=axis)
    h = np.zeros(N, dtype=Xf.dtype)
    if N % 2 == 0:
        h[0] = h[N // 2] = 1
        h[1:N // 2] = 2
    else:
        h[0] = 1
        h[1:(N + 1) // 2] = 2

    if x.ndim > 1:
        print("Hello World")
        ind = [np.newaxis] * x.ndim
        ind[axis] = slice(None)
        h = h[tuple(ind)]
    x = ifft(Xf * h, axis=axis)
    return x
```

Windowed RMS

```py
def window_rms(a, window_size):
  a2 = np.power(a,2)
  window = np.ones(window_size)/float(window_size)
  return np.sqrt(np.convolve(a2, window, 'valid'))
```

I need to build a jerk detector, by merging the envelope of several peaks caused by an event (Any value above 1.57 m/s^2 is considered a peak).
Last part is where I am getting stuck.

I have tried peak detection of scipy , have not got right result.

***Code***

```py
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,12)
# plt.plot(x)
# For zooming
# plt.ylim(4500, 5000)
plt.plot(envelope2)
plt.axhline(1.57)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(envelope2, prominence =1.57)      # BEST!
plt.plot(peaks, envelope2[peaks], "xr")
plt.legend(['RMS'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Used zero crossing

***Code***

```py
zero_crosses_rate = np.nonzero(np.diff(envelope > 1.57))[0]
print(zero_crosses_rate,envelope[zero_crosses_rate])
# printing original list
print("The original list : " + str(zero_crosses_rate))
 
# Using list slicing
# Separating odd and even index elements
odd = zero_crosses_rate[::2] 
even = zero_crosses_rate[1::2]
 
# print result
print(odd)
print(envelope2[odd])
print(even)
print(envelope2[even])
print("even bigger then odd that is considered jerk")
```

Also use modified Zscore , same could not understand, so could not work with it.

All in all consider me a lay man willing to follow guidance and learn with open mind seeking help.

Comment: "values beyond 1.57 g " is NOT jerk . Jerk is the time derivative of acceleration. Please clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to define what you mean by "multiple jerks instead of one".  Do you mean **one** event that has a duration longer than one accelerometer sample?  Or do you mean that the acceleration is undergoing a strong oscillation, with a non-monotonic change in acceleration reading?

Comment: Note on @Hilmar's comment: one g has the units $\mathrm{m / s^2}$.  Jerk is the time derivative of acceleration, so it has the units $\mathrm{m / s^3}$, or perhaps $\mathrm{g / s}$.

Comment: What you need is a differentiator (that will get you instantaneous jerk) and then you need to smooth that noisy instantaneous jerk out a little with a gentle LPF.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Can you point me to an example code or something similar.

Comment: The post id dying I have not yet resolved the doubt @TimWescott .

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson

Comment: @Hilmar do reconsider

Comment: @gladi8er: you were **very clearly asked to edit the question**, and given guidance as to what information is missing.  Until you do that _we_ can't answer, and _you_ should not expect much activity.

Comment: The visual representation of the problem is as follows .

Comment: Does the actual value of the accelerometer matter, other than that it's above 1.57g? What can't you just threshold it? `if (a > 1.57g) { jerk = 1; } else {jerk = 0;}` ? And then, potentially, filter that under/over threshold value.

Comment: @PeterK. It does not matter , if it is less than 1.57 m/s^2 (0.16g), One of the step is to doing just that (threshold), but the no of values peaks that come out of it are too much tha expected.